# File.write doesn't write exactly what I want

Tags: ruby, file, binary

I have a very very simple example:

```
content = [0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x0D, 0x0A] # "Hello\r\n"
f = File.new("PATH", "w")
content.each {|b| f.write(b.chr)}
f.close
```

I tried to write something to files and then I discovered, that Ruby writes for each `\r` a `\r` and for each `\n` a `\r\n`. So when I run my code example, Ruby doesn't write `Hello\r\n` into the file, it writes `Hello\r\r\n`. **Is there a way to prevent this or to write each byte without adding other bytes?**

Comment: can you try, just `wb` instead of `w`.. If works, I would suggest some other way to write your code.

Comment: Your result cannot be reproduced. In my environment, what is written by your code is `"Hello\r\n"`.

Comment: @sawa I think OP is in *windows*.. But it is my guess, not sure..

Comment: Yes. I'm running windows; @arup It works :) When you write this as an answer, I can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: @Cubinator73 Yes.. I put it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason mentioned in the documentation [`IO Open Mode`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode)

> "b" - Binary file mode. Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows and sets external encoding to ASCII-8BIT unless explicitly specified.

Thus you need to use `'wb'` instead of `'w'` to resolve your issue.

You can write code something like below :

```
content = [0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x0D, 0x0A] # "Hello\r\n"
f = File.new("PATH", "wb")
content.each {|b| f.write(b.chr)}
f.close
```